# Node.js read big file, edit and display

Tags: node.js

Im trying to read a file and pass it to a webpage. The problem is that the file is rather big. Its a list with links to profiles of people and it currently contains over 250.000 different people. What i want to do is take a link. get the name out of the url and display the name that has the original links to the names profile. This in itself isn't that much of a problem but because its so many names it would crash the page. So i need some help sending me in the right direction. I have already been looking at createReadStream to do this but I have a hard time understanding it.

The file is build like this:

```
<https://example.com/profile/123456/lastname-firstname>.
<https://example.com/profile/123457/lastname-firstname>.
<https://example.com/profile/123458/lastname-firstname>.
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

I was originaly using the stream function in combination with readline but i ended up using line-by-line. The main upside to this is that it allows me to pause the stream and continue when i want to.

```
var LineByLineReader = require('line-by-line');

var lr = new LineByLineReader('/url/to/file');

//get line count for file
var lineCount = 0;
var display = 0;

lr.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('err');
});

lr.on('line', function(line) {
  // increment line count
  lineCount++;


  //do something with data and parse it to the html
  var name = line.split(' ')[0].split('/')[5].replace('>','').replace(/-/g,' ');
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += `<li>` + name + `</li>`;

    //stop at a 100 lines
    if( lineCount > display+100){
        lr.pause();
    }
});

lr.on('end', function () {
  console.log('done loading');
});

//load next 100 when you reach the bottom of the page
$(window).scroll(function() {   
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
    display = display + 100;
    lr.resume();
    }
});
```